# App Submission for Showdown

Tags: application-development, application-submission

If I submit my app to the ARB today, can I make any changes before Monday?.  Or will the ARB consider my app based on the version that was submitted on the submission day? ie If I make changes will I have to resubmit.

Obviously if they suggest changes I will have to resubmit.  But what if there are no suggestions for change.  Will they grab the latest versions of apps at the end of the competition time?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  It didn't quite answer my question.  I wanted to know if I could submit get feed back and the submit again.  I know I had 'till the end of the week but I was travelling and wanted to try and get it in early. Obviously not important any more.  \

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had ansered that, but perhaps I wasn't clear enough. In any case, this question is answered on the FAQ at http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/faq/. See "Are app updates allowed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got until Monday to make any changes and submit your app. Any submissions after Monday 00:01 UTC will not qualify for the contest, so you've still got more than 3 days to finish off your app!

Check out the countdown banner on the [Ubuntu App Showdown site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/).

Comment: But according to countdown widget we still have a time until Monday 23:59 UTC, could you confirm that submission are closed now? Tnx.

Comment: The countdown seems wrong, I'll remove it from the page, thanks for the heads up!