# When exactly will the App Showdown stop accepting submissions?

Tags: application-development

It is not quite obvious if there is official time until which app submission still be accepted :)

According to rules:

> You’ve got 3 weeks to develop a new app, until the 9th July 2012

Countdown widget, right now, says 1 day 10:11:47:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/

Comment: To close voters: I see no reason to close this as "too localized." Anyone who thinks "When did the 2012 App Showdown stop accepting submissions?" would be an acceptable question now (or would close it as a duplicate of this) should really not consider this too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From David Planella, who is App Developer Community Liaison and one of judges for current contest:

> Any submissions after Monday 00:01 UTC will not qualify for the contest.

https://askubuntu.com/a/160294/3965

See also comments, he confirmed that countdown widget are wrong

Answer (score 2):

I would **definitely** submit before the deadline, given the errors people seem to be having with packaging/uploading.

In any case, even if your submission goes through, after say 1200 UTC on July 10, 2012 (to account for time zone differences), the App Review Board can simply decline to consider it since it was late.

Comment: So, deadline is 23:59 UTC on July 09, 2012, right?

Comment: Just wondering, because rules says until the 9th July 2012, but according to countdown widget we have one more day, i.e. still can submit anytime on Monday.

Comment: Monday is 9th July, you can submit any time **until 23:59 UTC** (which can be as early as 12:00 in your time zone)

Comment: Okay, but how about this: https://plus.google.com/events/cpn1ti9o4lgebkmug0df9ro356k/111697084657487423167 is it official even page?

Comment: I wouldn't count on that calendar/event - I'd trust the official countdown clock over that.

Comment: that event has been announced on reddit by David Planella who is App Developer Community Liaison and one of judges for current contest. See also his answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/160294/3965

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu App Developer Showdown will stop on 9th July 2012, at midnight, 23:59 UTC.