# What is the remaining time for Ubuntu app showdown?

Tags: application-development

Here (http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/) it says 1 Day 09:32:20.. so 1 day and 9 hours or 9 hours? I am asking because today is sunday...

Comment: 1 Day 10 hours, 6 minutes and 55 seconds here (GMT+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu App Developer Showdown ends on 9th June at midnight (23:59 UTC).

Comment: so it is 1 day plus the remaining.. ok thanks!

Comment: @Bong.Da.City, unfortunately there is no time remained, it's ended on Monday 00:01 UTC, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/160294/3965) and comments below it. David Planella is App Developer Community Liaison and one of judges for current contest, so, it's official answer.